# Item below charms bar gets invoked when search is clicked

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

I have created a page with horizontal layout listview with enough items added to it have a horizontal scrollbar. When you click an item in de listview it navigates to a different page with some details about the clicked item.

Now I have added search functionality to my app by use of the search contract. That's where the problem arises. When you open the charms bar, it overlays over the listview which is good. But when I click the search icon in the charms bar search is opened, but also the listitem's (which is below the charms bar ) click event  is getting invoked.

Anyone else who has seen this behaviour? It feels like a bug to me in the charms bar? Hopefully someone has seen this too and has a solution to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it yesterday on the RTM version and it seems that this issue is fixed in the RTM version.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

One quick thought is that your app is activated from the OnSearchActivated method when the user invokes a search; you could possibly add/remove event handlers in there.

Comment: I will see if i can isolate this issue and create a test project. It actually is the gridview in xaml which i'm using. In addition, my app is already running when activating search.

Answer (score 0):

Nice try, but whatever you do (Dispatching, Timer...), the click event is raised prior the OnSearchActivated.

Btw, we've "fixed" this problem by providing the view margin of 86 pixels on the right (I measured the Charm bar, and no matter what resolution, it's 86 pixels).
To keep the view symmetric, we also provided 86 pixels on the left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried that too but that's not really good for the design of my app. Hopefully have time to night, to check if there are properties/events that give the status of the charms bar. Hopefully this is fixed with the RTM version.